# How to scroll through the results when executing a command with :term in vim

Tags: vim

When executing a command in the vim terminal, the output result of the terminal may be too long to display on the position screen. At that time, I would like to know how to scroll through the results on the screen above.

Comment: A screenshot would help us understand what you call "position screen" and "screen above".

Comment: please tell us the version of your vim.

Comment: You can use terminal normal mode (`<C-w>N` IIRC) to scroll at least, but it prevents further output until you go back into insert mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use `less` for a pager-type output which you can scroll.

Another, way of doing this is going into a normal mode for terminal by pressing `<C-w>N` (Ctrl+w followed by Shift+n). This will drop you in a normal mode inside terminal.

Answer (score -1):

There is a plan B, which you can use `less`
In your vim terminal:

> `"your command" | less`

Because `less` support scroll up and down using arrow keys